# Session Management in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

We  are trying to build one simple website using force.com sites.Here User logged into website and need to perform different actions by moving to different VF pages.

We are facing a Problem to maintaine Session of particular user. We need help regarding how to maintaine session for particular user.

Kindly give your help. Please provide any sample code.

Thanks.

Comment: You must be talking about holding session toksen i guess?.What plateform your are using?

Comment: Exactly..i am working on force.com where i am using Apex and visuvalforce pages for development.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ;)

Think about it, you can store usernames/passwords in your data objects and if they allow you to login and maintain a session for that user and use it to walk around apex pages and builtin forms why would you buy a salesforce license? You could operate a 1000 employees rig with just one administrative license and a site URL. For that reason salesforce does not allow you session control, it grants you one when you buy and expense a license.

For sites, you have to purchase either `Customer Portal` license or volume-based `High Volume Customer Portal` set and then use those to "promote" a contact into a login user with the above license. Then, when that user logs into site it has its own session.

Answer (score 0):

This document http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites might be of great help.

This tutorial shows you how to authenticate users on Force.com Sites. It provides a description of Customer Portal, which is needed for the authentication, and shows you how to set up such a site and process to allow site visitors to become authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

The points on customer portal are correct, and you have to pay for these licences. If you build your own auth on Force.com Sites and salesforce.com finds out they'll be very unhappy. That said you can still do it using cookies (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm) but it's not perfect because it's client-side.

I highly recommend that you steer clear of this approach though. You're better off building your UI layer on another platform (Google App Engine or Heroku) and using web services created on the Force.com platform through that UI.